# Simplifying my program to convert numbers to from one base to another

Tags: c++

I'm taking a beginner C++ course. I received an assignment telling me to write a program that converts an arbitrary number from any base between binary and hex to another base between binary and hex. I was asked to use separate functions to convert to and from base 10. It was to help us get used to using arrays. (We already covered passing by reference previously in class.) I already turned this in, but I'm pretty sure this wasn't how I was meant to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int to_dec(char value[], int starting_base);
char* from_dec(int value, int ending_base);

int main() {
    char value[30];
    int starting_base;
    int ending_base;
    cout << "This program converts from one base to another, so long as the bases are" << endl
        << "between 2 and 16." << endl
        << endl;
input_numbers:
    cout << "Enter the number, then starting base, then ending base:" << endl;
    cin >> value >> starting_base >> ending_base;
    if (starting_base < 2 || starting_base > 16 || ending_base < 2 || ending_base > 16) {
        cout << "Invalid base(s). ";
        goto input_numbers;
    }
    for (int i=0; value[i]; i++) value[i] = toupper(value[i]);
    cout << "Base " << ending_base << ": " << from_dec(to_dec(value, starting_base), ending_base) << endl
        << "Press any key to exit.";
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int to_dec(char value[], int starting_base) {
    char hex[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    long int return_value = 0;
    unsigned short int digit = 0;
    for (short int pos = strlen(value)-1; pos > -1; pos--) {
        for (int i=0; i<starting_base; i++) {
            if (hex[i] == value[pos]) {
                return_value+=i*pow((float)starting_base, digit++);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return return_value;
}

char* from_dec(int value, int ending_base) {
    char hex[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char *return_value = (char *)malloc(30);
    unsigned short int digit = (int)ceil(log10((double)(value+1))/log10((double)ending_base));
    return_value[digit] = 0;
    for (; value != 0; value/=ending_base) return_value[--digit] = hex[value%ending_base];
    return return_value;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is more advanced than it was meant to be. How do you think I was supposed to do it?

I'm essentially looking for two kinds of answers:

1. Examples of what a simple solution like the one my teacher probably expected would be.
2. Suggestions on how to improve the code.

Comment: Looks like your instructor is teaching you C minus its stdio plus C++'s input/output.  In C++, one would use `std::string`, `std::vector`, `new`, etc. instead of `char *` arrays, and `malloc`.

Comment: malloc wasn't something we covered in class. I just needed to pass back the string from the function which became an improvised lesson in memory allocation and data destruction for me. I skipped the free call out of sheer laziness since it's called only once and terminating the app frees it anyway. On that note, we didn't cover conio.h either; I just didn't like system calling pause and read about the library before.

Comment: OK, but remember that `conio.h` is non-standard, and also there are better ways of doing what you are doing in C++.  Hopefully you will learn those in your class, and maybe a later exercise would be to do the same thing but in a "C++-fu" way.

Comment: What do you recommend instead of conio.h?

Comment: Also, what would be the C++-fu way?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need the inner loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<starting_base; i++) {
```

What is its purpose?

Rather, you should get the character at `value[ pos ]` and convert it to an integer. The conversion depends on base, so it may be better to do it in a separate function.

You are defining `char hex[ 16 ]` twice, once in each function. It may better to do it at only one place.

---

**EDIT 1:**
Since this is "homework" tagged, I cannot give you the full answer. However, here is an example of how to_dec() is supposed to work. (Ideally, you should have constructed this!)

Input:

```
  char * value = 3012, 
  int base = 4,
```

Math:

```
Number = 3 * 4^3 + 0 * 4^2 + 1 * 4^1 + 2 * 4^0 = 192 + 0 + 4 + 2 = 198
```

Expected working of the loop:

```
  x = 0
  x = 4x + 3 = 3
  x = 4x + 0 = 12
  x = 4x + 1 = 49
  x = 4x + 2 = 198

  return x;
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Fair enough! So, here is some more :-)

Here is a code sketch. Not compiled or tested though. This is direct translation of the example I provided earlier.

```
unsigned
to_dec( char * inputString, unsigned base )
{
  unsigned rv = 0; // return value
  unsigned c;      // character converted to integer

  for( char * p = inputString; *p; ++p ) // p iterates through the string
  {
    c = *p - hex[0];
    rv = base * rv + c;
  }

  return rv;
}
```

Comment: Could you give any examples of what you're proposing? I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: I know it's bad form to give people complete answers to homework questions, but I don't think that applies when the homework has already been done and turned in. ;) Anyway, I understand the method of multiplying it (In fact, the first time I scripted something like this I used that method.), but how do you propose eliminating the inner loop? UniquePhoton's method?

Comment: +1 for the example. Thanks! Is there any reason you assigned p to inputString? Couldn't you just have used inputString itself there?

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from GOTO statements unless they are absolutely necessary. GOTO statements are easy to use but will lead to 'spaghetti code'.

Try using a loop instead. Something along the lines of this:

```
bool base_is_invalid = true;
while ( base_is_invalid ) {

    cout << "Enter the number, then starting base, then ending base:" << endl;
    cin >> value >> starting_base >> ending_base;

    if (starting_base < 2 || starting_base > 16 || ending_base < 2 || ending_base > 16)
        cout << "Invalid number. ";
    else
        base_is_invalid = false;

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. You'll have to explain to me how that's better than what I wrote. All I can see is that you added some totally unnecessary logic and variables to make it do the same thing.

Comment: You're right they do exactly the same thing and the while loop is more code. It really makes no difference in a short program like this but as your programs increase in size GOTO statements will make your code unstructured, hard to read, and usually a nightmare to maintain. 

It's better to get into the habit of not using them especially when you're just starting out with C++.

Comment: That kind of "one size fits all" logic bothers me, and I have the distinct feeling you just insinuated I'm an idiot. A statement like "You should never use gotos or else your code will be a mess." operates under the assumption that the coder is too inept to ever be able to use gotos in a clean fashion. Either that or it presupposes that any use of goto is automatically an unclean use which strikes me as even more absurd.

Comment: Actually he's totally right. "You should never use gotos or else your code will be a mess." is true. Stop being so stuck up or you'll never learn anything.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's when you believe what other people tell you to believe without ever questioning it that you'll never learn anything. I have reason to believe he's wrong, so if you wish to convince me otherwise, you will have to provide me a reason in turn. And if that's called being stuck up, then I will wear that badge with pride.

Comment: @Spin City: Edger Dijkstra wrote an article called `A case against the GO TO statement`. He was probably more intelligent that either you or me, so I would heed his advice... and check his reasons. Niklaus Wirth (then editor of Communications of the ACM) wrote the ACM famous letter: `Go To Statement Considered Harmful`

Comment: "Please don't fall into the trap of believing that I am terribly dogmatical about [the go to statement]. I have the uncomfortable feeling that others are making a religion out of it, as if the conceptual problems of programming could be solved by a single trick, by a simple form of coding discipline!" -Edsger W. Dijkstra

Comment: There is also Donald Knuth's paper: Structured Programming With Go To Statements - http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf

Comment: My view is that gotos, used judiciously, are fine. And judicious use is not "avoid unless absolutely necessary" (Böhm and Jacopini already proved that essentially means "never use gotos" since any goto statement can be restructured to avoid its use.) but rather "use it whenever it provides for the cleanest and clearest flow control" and when it is reasonable for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: How about using a `do...while` loop? `do { ... } while (starting_base < 2 || starting_base > 16 || ending_base < 2 || ending_base > 16);`?

Comment: @spincity. Ok, go get a dev job and start writing gotos in production c++ code. I guarantee your colleagues will bitch at you. 
Also, your code is only like 100 lines long, and it's already a mess.

Comment: @Spin City: You actually make a pretty good case about using goto here (it's a very simple program, and it's very apparent what that label + goto are doing).  However, one thing to consider is that pretty much all branch control mechanisms are essentially the same other than minor semantics, and a key choice in usage is the *intent* of your branching.  Here, your intent is that if you want to keep asking the user to input until it is valid, which implies that you want to loop until a conditional, which is a `do { } while ();` loop.

Comment: @Alok and @Tanzelax: Ordinarily I would do that, but it gets messy since I also want it to `cout << "Invalid number. ";` if the while statement checks true, and to do that I need an if statement inside the loop instead of being able to use the loop's check. That's when I felt using the loop just became overly circuitous. In the end, the flow control came out neater to my eyes by just using a single if block with a goto.

Comment: @SP: That's just trying to peer pressure me into avoiding gotos. And if you think the code is a mess, feel free to post a new answer pointing out which parts specifically are messy and why with suggested improvements?

Comment: @Spin City:  As long as you're in the early stages of learning, I'd strongly suggest avoiding `goto`s.  Once you get a lot of experience in the language, you might find a place where it's indicated.  In well over seven years of jobs doing mostly C++ programming, I haven't found one.

Comment: @SP: You are incredibly naïve if you think there are no gotos in any production C++ code. In fact, the production code I'm working on has gotos in it.

Comment: I think it's too hard to make the case for or against GOTOs. It is too subjective and while there are definitely valid cases, why present a case of whether the GOTO is valid or not? Simply make a habit of not using it (even if it is perfectly valid) and in the long run it'll be to your benefit. Use a function or use conditionals and if you follow good naming convention you'll still maintain the same readability. I would love to see an example where a GOTO is the only way to go but I don't think this is an ideal example.

Comment: @nevets1219: Getting out of 7 nested if's is a perfect valid way to use a goto.

Comment: Can't you make the nested IF a function and return instead? I guess both seems like a valid approach. I guess the function approach isn't that good if you want to follow a strict one exit point only style.

Comment: But here's the thing, nevets1219: You haven't eliminated the goto; your goto is now just a return statement and you wrapped it in a function. That's fine if you had other reasons to make it a function anyway, but otherwise this sort of behavior ranks up with writing `do ... while (false)` so you can `break` for forward jumps. In the end, you're just writing some roundabout code so you can get your goto and convince yourself you didn't actually write a goto.

Comment: Don't forget the context of Dijkstra's GOTO debate.  BASIC had recently been invented, and the *only* control flow it had, besides FOR...NEXT loops, was GOTO, IF...GOTO, and ON...GOTO.  (FORTRAN, on which BASIC was based, had similar deficiencies.)  So not only did you have to use GOTO to emulate break and continue, but you also had to use it to emulate if...else, switch, while, and do...while.  Programs had a *lot* of GOTOs.

And so, when "structured programming" became popular, there was a severe backlash against GOTO.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize arrays by string literals (notice that the terminating \0 is not included because the size of the array doesn't permit that):

```
char const hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Or just use a pointer to the string literal for the same effect:

```
char const* hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Comment: Is the terminating \0 actually not included or does it merely overflow and corrupt some memory?

Comment: You get a compile error if you try to make the array any shorter. The standard has a special rule for \0 being not copied if it doesn't fit.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! What about the pointer? Does that have the trailing null byte?

Comment: @Spin, C++'s rationale is "When these non-terminated arrays are manipulated by standard string routines, there is potential for major catastrophe."

Comment: Does that mean that my character array would be terminated with a null byte anyway?

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up. And... I'm a little confused now. I understand what's happening fine, but I don't understand why it's done this way. If they're worried about non-terminated char arrays causing problems when passed through cstring functions, wouldn't they just terminate all char arrays with nulls for good measure? This approach strikes me as a little... odd.

Comment: @Spin City:  How do you terminate the `hex[16]` with a null character when it's already got 16 characters in it?  The compiler would need to extend it by one position, and that's not something the C++ people wanted to happen.  If you specify something inconsistently, that's an error in C++.  (It wasn't in C, for other reasons.  C and C++ are two distinct languages sharing a fairly large common core, and they should be programmed in distinctly different ways.)

Comment: Right, the inconsistency is what bothers me. The only thing it accomplishes in my eyes is making declaring character arrays more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

to_dec() looks to complicated, here is my shot at it:

```
int to_dec(char* value, int starting_base)
{
    int return_value = 0;
    for (char* cur = value + strlen(value) - 1; cur >= value; cur--) {
        // assuming chars are ascii/utf: 0-9=48-57, A-F=65-70
        // faster than loop
        int inval = *cur - 48;
        if (inval > 9) {
            inval = *cur - 55;
            if (inval > 15) {
                // throw input error
            }
        }
        if (inval < 0) {
            // throw input error
        }
        if (inval >= starting_base) {
            // throw input error
        }
        // now the simple calc
        return_value *= starting_base;
        return_value += inval;
    }
    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Wouldn't it be better to replace "inval = *cur - 55;" with "inval -= 7;" though?

Comment: Yes that is the same, but I find -55 is better for readability.

Comment: If you mean for 48 to represent the character '0', just put '0' instead of 48.  Keep it readable and let the compiler do the translation.  `int inval = *cur - '0';`

Answer (score 1):

for the initial conversion from ascii to an integer, you can also use a lookup table (just as you are using a lookuptable to to the conversion the other way around) , which is much faster then searching through the array for every digit.

```
 int to_dec(char value[], int starting_base) 
 {
      char asc2BaseTab = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,11,12,13,14,15, //0-9 and A-F (big caps)
                         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,  //unused ascii chars
                          10,11,12,13,14,15};  //a-f (small caps)

      srcIdx = strlen(value);
      int number=0;
      while((--srcIdx) >= 0)
      {
           number *= starting_base;          
           char asciiDigit = value[srcIdx];
           if(asciiDigit<'0' || asciiDigit>'f') 
           {
                //display input error
           } 
           char digit = asc2BaseTab[asciiDigit - '0'];
           if(digit == -1)
           {
                 //display input error
           }
           number += digit;
      }
      return number;
 }
```

p.s. excuses if there are some compile errors in this...I couldn't test it...but the logic is sound.

Answer (score 1):

In your description of the assignment as given it says:

"I was asked to use separate functions to convert to and from base 10."

If that is really what the teacher meant and wanted, which is doubtful, your code doesn't do that:

```
int to_dec(char value[], int starting_base)
```

is returning an int which is a binary number. :-)  Which in my opinion does make more sense.

Did the teacher even notice that?

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are different languages, and with different styles of programming. You better not to mix them. ([Where C and C++ differ](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html))

If you are trying to use C++, then:

Use std::string instead of char* or char[].

```
int to_dec(string value, int starting_base);
string from_dec(int value, int ending_base);
```

No any mallocs, use new/delete. But actually C++ manages memory automatically. The memory is freed as soon as variable is out of scope (unless you are dealing with pointers). And pointers are the last thing you need to deal with.

We don't need here any lookup tables, just a magic string.

```
string hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";//The index of the letter is its decimal value. A is 10, F is 15.
//usage
char c = 'B';
int value = hex.find( c );//works only with uppercase;
```

The refactored to_dec can be like that.

```
int to_dec(string value, int starting_base) {
  string hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  int result = 0;
  for (int power = 0; power < value.size(); ++power) {
    result += hex.find( value.at(value.size()-power-1) ) * pow((float)starting_base, power);
  }
  return result;
}
```

And there is a more elegant algorithm to convert from base 10 to any other
See [there](http://www.searchmarked.com/math/how-to-convert-from-base-10-decimal-to-any-other-base.php) for example. You have the opportunity to code it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

In your from_dec function, you're converting the digits from left to right.  An alternative is to convert from right to left.  That is,

```
std::string from_dec(int n, int base)
{
    std::string result;
    bool is_negative = n < 0;

    if (is_negative)
    {
       n = - n;
    }

    while (n != 0)
    {
        result = DIGITS[n % base] + result;
        n /= base;
    }

    if (is_negative)
    {
        result = '-' + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, you won't need the log function.

(BTW, to_dec and from_dec are inaccurate names.  Your computer doesn't store numbers in base 10.)

Answer (score 1):

Got this question on an interview once and brainfarted and spun wheels for a while. Go figure. Anyway, a couple years later I'm going through Math and Physics for Programmers to brush up for positions that are more math intensive than what I've been doing. CH1 "assignment" has

```
// Write a function ConvertBase(Number, Base1, Base2) which takes a 
// string or array representing an integer in Base1 and converts it
// into base Base2, returning the new string.
```

So, I took an approach mentioned above: I convert string in arbitrary base to UINT64, then I convert UINT64 back to arbitrary base:

```
CString ConvertBase(const CString& strNumber, int base1, int base2)
{
   return ValueToBaseString(BaseStringToValue(strNumber, base1), base2);
}
```

Each of the subfunctions has a recursive solution. Here's one for example:

```
UINT64 BaseStringToValue(const CString& strNumber, int base)
{
    if (strNumber.IsEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    CString outDigit = strNumber.Right(1);
    UINT64 output = DigitToInt(outDigit[0]);
    CString strRemaining = strNumber.Left(strNumber.GetLength() - 1);
    UINT64 val = BaseStringToValue(strRemaining, base);
    output += val * base;
    return output;
}
```

I find the other one slightly harder to grasp mentally, but it works roughly the same way.

I also implemented DigitToInt and IntToDigit which work just like they sound. You can take some neat shortcuts there, by the way, if you realize that chars are ints then you don't need huge switch statements:

```
int DigitToInt(wchar_t cDigit)
{
    cDigit = toupper(cDigit);
    if (cDigit >= '0' && cDigit <= '9')
    {
        return cDigit - '0';
    }
    return cDigit - 'A' + 10;
}
```

and unit tests are really your friend here:

```
typedef struct 
{
    CString number;
    int base1;
    int base2;
    CString answer;
} Input;

Input input[] =
{ 
    { "345678", 10, 16, "5464E"},
    { "FAE211", 16, 8, "76561021" },
    { "FAE211", 16, 2, "111110101110001000010001"},
    { "110110111", 2, 10, "439" } 
}; 

(snip)

for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]) ; i++)
{
    CString result = ConvertBase(input[i].number, input[i].base1, input[i].base2);
    printf("%S in base %d is %S in base %d (%S expected - %s)\n", (const WCHAR*)input[i].number, 
                                               input[i].base1, 
                                               (const WCHAR*) result, 
                                               input[i].base2,
                                               (const WCHAR*) input[i].answer,
                                               result == input[i].answer ? "CORRECT" : "WRONG");
}
```

And here's the output:

```
345678 in base 10 is 5464E in base 16 (5464E expected - CORRECT)
FAE211 in base 16 is 76561021 in base 8 (76561021 expected - CORRECT)
FAE211 in base 16 is 111110101110001000010001 in base 2 (111110101110001000010001 expected - CORRECT)
110110111 in base 2 is 439 in base 10 (439 expected - CORRECT)
```

Now I took some shortcuts in coding by using CString types, etc. I was giving no consideration to efficiency or performance, I just wanted to solve the algorithm with easiest coding possible.

It can help to understand how these algorithms are recursive if you write them like so: Say you want to determine the "value" of the "string" B4A3, which is in base 13. You know it's 3 + 13(A) + 13(13)(4) + 13(13)(13)(B) Another way to write that is: 0+3+13(A+13(4+13(B))) - and voila! Recursion.

Comment: That's not a C++ algorithm, though. It'll work only under MS VC++ compilers with the `CString` MFC/ATF class..

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the things already mentioned, I would suggest using the new-operator instead of free. The advantages of new are that it also does call constructors - which is irrelevant here since you're using a POD type, but important when it comes to objects such as std::string or your own custom classes - and that you can overload the new operator to suit your specific needs (which is irrelevant here, too :p). But don't go ahead using malloc for PODs and new for classes, since mixing them is considered bad style.

But okay, you got yourself some heap memory in from_dec... but where is it freed again? Basic rule: memory that you malloc (or calloc etc) must be passed to free at some point. The same rule applies to the new-operator, just that the release-operator is called delete. Note that for arrays, you need new[] and delete[]. DON'T ever allocate with new and release with delete[] or the other way around, since the memory won't be released correctly.

Nothing evil will happen when your toy program won't release the memory... I guess your PC has got enough RAM to cope with it and when you shut down your program, the OS releases the memory anyway.. but not all programs are (a) that tiny and (b) shut down often.

Also I'd avoid conio.h, since this is not portable. You're not using the most complicated IO, so the standard headers (iostream etc) should do.

Likewise, I think most programmers using modern languages follow the rule "Only use goto if other solutions are really crippled or tons of more work". This is a situation that can be easily solved by using loops, as shown by emceefly. In your program the goto is easy to handle, but you won't be writing such small programs forever, will you? ;)
I, for example, was presented with some legacy code recently.. 2000 lines of goto-littered code, yay! Trying to follow the code's logical flow was almost impossible ("Oh, jump ahead 200 lines, great... who needs context anyway"), even harder was to rewrite the damn thing.

So okay, your goto doesn't hurt here, but where's the benefit? 2-3 lines shorter? Doesn't really matter overall (if you're paid by lines of code, this could also be a major disadvantage ;)). Personally I find the loop version more readable and clean.

As you see, most of the points here can be ignored easily for your program, since it's a toy program. But when you think of larger programs, they make more sense (hopefully) ;)